# DNS lookup failed with wamp server

Tags: php, dns, wamp

I have installed wamp 2.5 and apache 2.4.9. I add in the www folder a simple php file. When I tried to access it from the localhost, I received the following message:

```
The server at main can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the
network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This
error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a
misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or
a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.
```

What is the solution for DNS lookup failed issue? I am using windows 7.

Comment: What did you type in the address bar to access it?

Comment: In localhost there was the folder that located in www wamp folder. I tried to access main folder in which main.php located and I received this error.

Comment: 1. What I meant is that did you type http://localhost or something else?

Comment: 2. Do you have IIS installed as well?

Comment: 3. Did you alter your Windows hosts files before?

Comment: Ok when I write in browser the path of file, browser opens it normally. However from localhost main gui when I tried open the  main folder icon it returned that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to access the webpage by typing `http://main/`. The issue is that Google-Chrome tries to resolve domain `main` and it fails as it does not exist.

One solution would be to add domain `main` to `hosts` file in `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`, more detailed help is provided [here](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file).

Better approach will be that check what is the name of the server you have configured in Apache with `ServerName` directive and try to use that.